# Angular 2 multiple modules

Tags: angular

I have an app which has multiple views like one is spreadsheet & other is the two-panel view, for both views navigation, searching & filters will be common. So I added a common module and imported that module to the main module & now trying to use common modules components in spreadsheet component. Well below is my code that will give the proper picture:

```
// Spreadsheet module - spreadsheet.module.ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Spreadsheet } from './components/spreadsheet.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ Spreadsheet ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class SpreadsheetModule { }

// Common module - common.module.ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TopNavigation } from './components/header.component';
import { Search } from './components/search.component';
import { AccountInfo } from './services/accountInfo';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ TopNavigation, Search ],
  providers: [ AccountInfo ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Now I am importing both this module to one main module which is:

```
// App module - app.module.ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module';
import { SpreadsheetModule } from './spreadsheet/spreadsheet.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, SpreadsheetModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So in my spreadsheet's component, I am trying to use header's (`TopNavigation`) template like `<top-nav></top-nav>` so this should show header.html content but its coming as blank. It's not giving any error as well. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Note: If I directly declare `TopNavigation` in `spreadsheet.module.ts` it works fine. But since navigation and search are common I don't want to declare it in every single modules that should only be in `app.module.ts`

Comment: Not sure about what you want exactly.

Comment: @nlr_p I want to include `header.component` template to `spreadsheet.component`, something like this `<spreadsheet><top-nav></top-nav></spreadsheet>` so in above case `<top-nav></top-nav>` is coming empty. But if I declare header.component directly to spreadsheet.module like `declarations: [ Spreadsheet, TopNavigation ],` it works fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things need to be done here:

First, export `TopNavigation` & `Search` components from the CommonModule so they can be used in other modules:

```
// Common module - common.module.ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TopNavigation } from './components/header.component';
import { Search } from './components/search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ TopNavigation, Search ],
  exports: [ TopNavigation, Search ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Secondly, the `CommonModule` should be imported by the Module that actually uses it. In your case the `SpreadSheet` module should import `CommonModule`

```
// Spreadsheet module - spreadsheet.module.ts
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Spreadsheet } from './components/spreadsheet.component';
import { CommonModule } from './common/common.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [ Spreadsheet ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class SpreadsheetModule { }
```

Modules do not inherit components are declared in other modules. So when you import `CommonModule` in `AppModule` it does not have any effect.

You can read [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module) for more info.

Comment: now I am getting this error: `Error: Error in ./Spreadsheet class Spreadsheet - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for AccountInfo!.` Actually I have a service which I have added in `common.module`, check I have updated common.module in my question

Comment: Its solved, I was calling AccountInfo at couple of places and from different paths, so its solved now, thanks a lot

Comment: you should use *exports* in your CommonModule instead of *schemas*